# SWIG Ruby template for vector of set of strings

Tags: c++, ruby, stl, swig

trying to use SWIG for ruby

my .i file

```
%module example
%{
#include "classifier.h"
%}

%include "std_vector.i"
%include "std_set.i"
%include "std_string.i"

%template(StringSetVector) std::vector<set<string> >;

%include "classifier.h"
```

i have managed to compile successfully with

```
swig -c++ -ruby example.i
g++ -c example_wrap.cxx -I/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/include/ruby-2.2.0
g++ -bundle -flat_namespace -undefined suppress {OBJS} example_wrap.o -o example.bundle
```

i am able to require the bundle successfully, but not the template.

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require './example.bundle'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> include StringSetVector
NameError: uninitialized constant StringSetVector
    from (irb):2
    from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Disregard what I wrote earlier.

I think you simply need to access `StringSetVector` in ruby as `Example::StringSetVector`.